# Can not shown the Breadcrumb using the recursive function PHP

Tags: php, function, recursion, breadcrumbs

If anyone can help me with display breadcrumbs using recursive function method in PHP.

I got this code :

```
function getCategoryTreeIDs($qs_type_id) {
        $crumbsql = "SELECT parent_id FROM lists WHERE id=$qs_type_id";
        $crumbresult = tep_db_query($crumbsql);
        $crumbrow = tep_db_fetch_array($crumbresult);
        $path = array();
        if (!$crumbrow['parent_id'] == '') {
            $path[] = $crumbrow['parent_id'];
            $path = array_merge($this->getCategoryTreeIDs($crumbrow['parent_id']), $path);
        }
        return $path;
}
function showCatBreadCrumb($qs_type_id) {
        $array = $this->getCategoryTreeIDs($qs_type_id);
        $numItems = count($array);
        for ($i = 0; $i<=$numItems-1; $i++) {
            echo $this->getNameLink($array[$i]) . ' &raquo; ';
        }
}
```

But, when i click on any links (categories), the breadcrumb didn't show up.
If there any mistake about the show breadcrumb code?

Any help would be appreciate. I already looking for clue for the last couple months.

Many thanks !

**EDIT** :
Code to display not using the "for" command.

```
   function getCategorytTreeIDs($qs_type_id) {
    global $lists;
    $crumbsql = "SELECT * FROM lists WHERE id=$qs_type_id";
    $crumbresult = mysql_query($crumbsql);
    $crumbrow = mysql_fetch_array($crumbresult);
    if($crumbrow['parent_id'] == 0) {
        $crumbprob = $crumbrow['problem'];
        return "<a href='index.php'>Home</a> > <a href='index.php?q=id/$qs_type_id'>".$crumbprob."</a> > ";
    } else {
        $crumbprob = $crumbrow['problem'];  
        return getCategoryTreeIDs($crumbrow['parent_id']). "<a href='index.php?q=id/$qs_type_id'>".$crumbprob."</a> >";
    }
}
```

To show the breadcrumb, i must type manually the function and the id number. Like this:

```
echo getCategoryTreeIDs(20);
```

My question is, how i can display the breadcrumb automatically when some users click on the categories id?

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to note is that when this works, there will be a raquo after the last breadcrumb. I suggest getting the array of breadcrumbs and `implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs)` instead of using for.

Comment: Why not try some debugging. Start with the first function. `print_r($crumbrow)` to make sure that it contains what you expect. Also, you do realize that none of the breadcrumbs are links, correct? You mention clicking on categories, but I assume you meant elsewhere.

Comment: I follow your suggest by changing the "for" command. See above post.

Comment: where is the `breadcrumb()` function defined that you mention on the 11th line of your edited code?

Comment: My mistake, breadcrumb() should be getCategoryTreeIDs. I edit the code again.

Answer (score 0):

To display breadcrumbs dynamically for requested pages, you will need to examine the `q` GET parameter.

```
list($qName, $qID) = explode('/', $_GET['q']); // for categories qName will be 
                                               // 'id' and qID will the be id
if($qName == 'id') {
    echo getCategoryTreeIDs($qID); //Outputs breadcrumbs for category pages
}
```